# Combining audio and multiple videos with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-filters

I am working on a ffmpeg script to combine two videos with one audio file. The first video file should start after about 6 seconds and the second after about 40 seconds, and there should be a padding with a black screen between the two videos.
However, it only seems to add the first video clones the final frame as the padding.

Here is my current script:

```
ffmpeg -i video_0.mp4 -i video_1.mp4 -i audio.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] tpad=start_duration=5927ms:start_mode=add:color=black:stop_mode=add:color=black; [1:v] tpad=start_duration=44901ms:start_mode=add:color=black:stop_mode=add:color=blackconcat=n=2" -map 2:a -f mp4 -movflags +faststart composite_recording.mp4
```

The final video timing should be:

00:00-00:06 -- black screen
00:06-00:24 -- first video
00:24-00:40 -- black screen
00:40-00:48 -- second video

I tried setting different values for the tpad start_duration for the second video and expected it to start the second video at around 40 seconds into the audio, however it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command:

`ffmpeg -y -i video_0.mp4 -i video_1.mp4 -i audio.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=duration=18,tpad=start_duration=6:start_mode=add:color=black:stop_mode=add:color=black[v0];[1:v] trim=duration=8,tpad=start_duration=16:start_mode=add:color=black:stop_mode=add:color=black[v1];[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]" -shortest -map "[v]" -map 2:a -f mp4 -movflags +faststart composite_recording.mp4`

---

- `[0:v]trim=duration=18` - trim video_0.mp4 to 18 seconds (may be required in case it is longer than 18 second).
  Same applied video_1.mp4 using `[1:v] trim=duration=8`.
- `[v0]` at the end of the `tpad` filter, stores the padded video to the temporary name `[v0]`.
  `[v1]` at the end of the second `tpad` stores to temporary name `[v1]`.
- `[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]` - concatenate the videos `[v0]` and `[v1]` and store to `[v]`.
- `-shortest` - optionaly keep the shortest between the audio and the video (required in case the audio is too long).
- `-map "[v]"` maps `[v]` to the output video.

---

For testing we may generate synthetic video files (with a counter that counts the seconds):

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=25 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 60 video_0.mp4`
`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=25 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 60 video_1.mp4`
`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=300 -acodec aac -ar 22050 -t 500 audio.mp4`